# How does CUDA work with windows 10+python35+keras+tensorflow?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras

Exact sampe Python script working on two computers one with CUDA and one without.
Machine with CUDA has a CPU with 8GB RAM, clock frequency 3.8GHz and 4 cores.
Keras.json does not specify device=CUDA but when the script runs Epoch 1 of 20 egts executed in 2040s
CPU use is 92.9% for python.exe (looks like a single thread). Memory use is 36%

Second machine w/o CUDA has CPU with 16GB RAM 2.1GHz clock and 2 cores.
Keras.json does not specify device=CUDA but when the script runs Epoch 1 of 20 egts executed in 6664s
CPU use is 29.2 % for python.exe (looks like a single thread). Memory use is 32%

How does one reconcile the difference in CPU use? Is CUDA playing a role here?

Any response is a good response. Thank you all

Comment: a factor of two is easily explained based on cpu frequency.  perhaps the cpu's cache size is smaller on the 2.1Ghz chip....it's copying/adding/multiplying a lot of numbers.  perhaps enough of a bottleneck to account for the extra slowness.  doubtful that cuda is playing a role.

Comment: @user1269942....you could be right may be CUDA is not playing a role. what puzzles me is what the CPU 2ith 38GHz with 4 cores so sbusy as oppose to the CPU with 2.1 GHz and 2 cores?

Comment: OK, do you have the same type/speed of RAM? peak transfer/read rate will depend on the type of ram and its frequency.  maybe the difference can be accounted for with the RAM speed.

Comment: @user1269942...CPU-Z software shows for the 3.8GHz machine the RAM is 8GB, its NB Frequency is 2008.8 MHz and DRAM frequency is 803.5 MHz. The 2.1GHz machine shows a 16GB RAm with NB Frequency 798.1 MHz and DRAM frequency also as 798.1MHz. I don't know what that means

Comment: NB(northbridge) is the controller between RAM/CPU/Video.  Since there isn't any headroom in the 2.1GHz machine, it could be a limiting factor.  Or, if both can copy at about 800MHz from RAM to CPU, then it's back to cache size.  It's probably both and we most likely cannot tell you exactly...background processes using the NB, cache size, cache frequency, will all affect the rate at which the CPU can acquire data from RAM.  Use CUDA and your numbers will be waaay faster!